# Method Interception, replace return value

Tags: ninject, aop

We’re using Ninject.Extensions.Interception (LinFu if it matters) to do a few things and I want to know if its possible to return a value form the method being intercepted.

EG

A Call is made into one of our repository methods
Our Interceptor gets the BeforeInvoke event, we use this to look into the ASP.NET Cache to see if there is any relevant data
-        Return the relevant data (this would cause the method to return immediately and NOT execute the body of the method
-        Or Allow the method to run as per normal

Extra points if in the AfterInvoke method we take a peek at the data being returned and add it to the cache.

Has anybody done something similar before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I assume that you derive from SimpleInterceptor. This will not allow to return imediately. Instead you have to implement the Iinterceptor interface. You can decide to call the intercepted method by calling the Proceed method on the invocation or not.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed using SimpleInterceptor; Thanks for pointing me in the direction of where to go (implement the Interface directly). 

Will see what happens in the next few days and give it a go.